# Kotlin-How can i put comma every three number like this 1,000,000,000

Tags: android, kotlin, text, android-inputtype

i have an issue and will be appreciated if u help me .

this is an example of my issue :

I have some variables like (10.000 , 20,000) that user can select them and increase there credit .

when user click and chose one of them it goes to bank gateway and after payment it goes back to my app .

I used a text view to get the amount . it's no problem with this .

the amount that stored and show to user is 10000 or 20000 or 100000 and i want to be like this 10,000 or 20,000 or 100,000

actually every three number put a comma .

code :

```
  private fun makepayment(amount: Long) {


        val progress = findViewById<RelativeLayout>(R.id.rl_progress)

        val purchase = ZarinPal.getPurchase(this)

        val payment: PaymentRequest = ZarinPal.getSandboxPaymentRequest()
        payment.merchantID = getString(R.string.MerchantId)
        payment.amount = amount
        payment.isZarinGateEnable(true)
        payment.description = getString(R.string.incresemoney)
        payment.setCallbackURL("returnfromzarinpal://mivebaranapp")



        purchase.startPayment(payment) {


                status, authority, paymentGatewayUri, intent ->

            if (status == 100) {

                progress.visibility = View.GONE
                startActivity(intent)

            } else {

                Toast.makeText(
                    this,
                    "خطایی در برقراری ارتباط با درگاه رخ داده ، لطفا دوباره امتحان کنید",
                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG
                ).show()


            }

        }

    }
```

```
private fun paymentVerification() {

    val textmoney: TextView = findViewById(R.id.money)
    val data: Uri? = intent.data

    val getpurchase = ZarinPal.getPurchase(this)


    getpurchase.verificationPayment(data) {

            isPaymentSuccess, refID, paymentRequest ->

        if (isPaymentSuccess) {


            textmoney.text = "${paymentRequest.amount} تومان  "


            Toast.makeText(this, "افزایش موجودی شما با موفقیت انجام شد ", Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                .show()

        } else {

            Toast.makeText(
                this,
                "در عملیات پرداخت خطایی رخ داده ، لطفا دوباره سعی کنید",
                Toast.LENGTH_LONG
            ).show()


        }


    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this :

```
textView.text = "%,d".format(100000)
```

Output :

```
100,000
```

Answer (score 0):

You can pass the amount as int to the function as an agrument and returns formatted string as per the requirement. As a separate funtion, it would be useful even if you change pattern in future and can be useful in multiple places.

```
fun applyPattern(d: Int): String? {
val numberFormat = NumberFormat.getInstance(Locale.US) as DecimalFormat
numberFormat.applyPattern("#,###")
return numberFormat.format(d)
}
```

Comment: Although this answer attemps to anwer the question, it would be far more useful if you gave a description on how this answer helps with the problem (in this case seems to be the applyPattern function)

Answer (score 0):

Here is my solution:

```
fun stylePrice(oldPrice: String): String {

    if (oldPrice.length > 3) {
        val reversed = oldPrice.reversed()
        var newPrice = ""
        for (i in oldPrice.indices) {
            newPrice += reversed[i]
            if ((i+1) % 3 == 0) {
                newPrice += ','
            }
        }
        val readyToGo = newPrice.reversed()

        // if you don't use it, when the number is (for example) 532,234
        // it will be like this: ,532,234
        // so we need it :-)
        if (readyToGo.first() == ',') {
            return readyToGo.substring(1) + " Dollars"
        }

        return "$readyToGo Dollars"
    }

    return "$oldPrice Dollars"
}
```

Samples of outputs: `2,000,000` or `2,000`